# here-api upgrade map tiles v2.1 to raster tiles v3 giving credentials error

Tags: raster, here-api

i'm updating our html5 website which is currently using maptiles v2.1 which is being discontinued.
we have updated geocoding, reverse geocoding, routing api calls all fine to the latest version using apikey instead of app_id and app_code.

the old url uses app_id and app_code in this format.

https://1.base.maps.api.here.com/maptile/2.1/maptile/newest/normal.day/18/130111/83381/256/png8?app_id=xxx&app_code=xxx

i've been trying to replace this with the raster tiles url in this format with the new apikey we have, ie:

https://maps.hereapi.com/v3/base/mc/7/66/42/png8?apikey=xxx

this is returning a 403 forbidden error: {"error":"Forbidden","error_description":"These credentials do not authorize access"}

the apikey works fine for the other api calls (geocode, routing, etc) but not this.
does our apikey not have access to the raster tiles api?

Comment: Hi ianw, thanks for choosing HERE, the raster tile V3 is not officially launched yet. We will update the info here once available: https://developer.here.com/documentation

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for choosing HERE, the raster tile V3 is not officially launched yet. We will update the info here once available: https://developer.here.com/documentation

Answer (score 0):

The HERE Raster Tile API v3 is now officially launched. The migration guide is available at https://www.here.com/docs/bundle/raster-tile-api-migration-guide/page/README.html.

As it states, you'll need a "HERE platform account" to use it, credentials from older "HERE developer accounts" don't work with that newer API.